# Comparing JSON value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to check if "T1000" exists as an approval "key" in the following JSON. If it exists, then I want to display the corresponding approval "value".

```
{"approvals": 
    [
         {"approval":
            {
               "id":"0121920",
               "key":"T100",
               "value":"Ben Tsu"
            }
         },
         {"approval":
            {
               "id":"",
               "key":"T1000",
               "value":"Amy Dong"
            }
         }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting JSON as an Ajax response. I'm trying to loop through all properties and match it to the value passed in as the parameter.

Here's my code but it only spits out object Object, object Object. So, if I have 5 properties, this code spits out object Object 5 times.

I'm passing inputFieldDefaultValue as a parameter to the plugin with the value being T1000. Hence, o.inputFieldDefaultValue.

```
$.each(response.approvals, function(index, approvals){ 
    if(approvals.approval.key == o.inputFieldDefaultValue){ 
         approvals.approval.value; 
    } 
});
```

If I do

```
$.each(response.approvals, function(index, approvals){ 
    if(approvals.approval.key == o.inputFieldDefaultValue){ 
         alert(approvals.approval.value); 
    } 
});
```

it alerts the corresponding value (Amy Dong) but it still writes object Object (as many times as the properties in the JSON response).

Answer (score 3):

You may access the values of the JSON object by using the following code that traverses the objects:

```
var approvals = obj.approvals;

for(var i = 0; i < approvals.length; i++)
{
  if(approvals[i].approval.key = 'T1000')
  {
    // Display approvals[i].approval.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's my code and it only spits out object Object, object Object.

I'm passing inputFieldDefaultValue as a parameter to the plugin and extending it. Hence, o.inputFieldDefaultValue.
      $.each(response.approvals, function(index, approvals){
   if(approvals.approval.key == o.inputFieldDefaultValue){
 approvals.approval.value;
   }
})

If I do alert(approvals.approval.value;), then I get the corresponding value.

Comment: First, please post code as an update to your question.  Second, that code is nothing like mine, so I'm not sure why you're posting it here.  Third, you're not doing anything with the value in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without jQuery. You just need `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var aListOfAllValuesFromKeysEqualsToT1000 = json.approvals.filter(function(approval) {
    return approval.key === "T1000";
}).map(function(approval) {
    return approval.value;
});
```

Then use `aListOfAllValuesFromKeysEqualsToT1000` to do whatever you want the values for.

Comment: You should mention that this is only supported by recent browsers.  For instance, IE9 is the first IE to support it.

Comment: True that. But now you've mentioned it for me :) +1

Answer (score 0):

you would first take your json and use JSON.parse(json) to get some object literals.  From there you would do

```
var ary = obj.approvals;
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
  var current = ary[i], val;
  if (current.key === 'T1000') {
    val = current.value;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
var approvals = obj.approvals;
$.each(approvals, function () {
    if (this.approval.key === 'T1000') {
        alert(this.approval.value);
    }
});
```