# How to get the diff between two JSONs?

Tags: javascript, python, json

Is there any library/script to compare two JSONs objects and show the diff between them?

Thanks

EDIT:
I want to do that using python OR jquery/javascript

Comment: what os, what tools do you have available?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192807/comparing-json-value-in-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108666/jquery-javascript-json-object-comparison

Comment: Compare part is simple for python. But, i can't figure out how to display diff and what is the diff?

Answer (score 0):

*comparing* the two JSONs is very simple (in all languages) - you just compare the strings. 

*showing the diffs* is a little more complicated - i guess that one need to deserialize the JSONs and compare the objects.